# Apache Ivy Best Practices

Tags: apache, configuration, ivy

Hi I'm reading up on Ivy for the first time and had a few quick questions:

1. Need confirmation: the IvyDE plugin is used to configure just the ivyconf.xml file for all workspace projects, correct?
2. Where does this ivyconf.xml live?  I'm running Windows 7 and can't find this hidden .ivy directory anywhere!
3. Where do you usually place a project's ivy.xml and other xml config files?

Thanks for any *nudges* in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

1. IvyDE allow you to resolve dependencies per project. You could use separate ivyconf.xml in different projects.
2. You could place ivyconf.xml (or ivysettings.xml) where you want. You could use one per project (as I do) or one for all projects (as I did before).
3. Usually I put ivy.xml beside Ant's build.xml in the root of my project. But ivysettings.xml I put in project/etc/ivysettings/ directory.

Comment: I'm interested in why you go for an ivysettings.xml per project. My team uses a single ivysettings.xml globally in Eclipse, so far without issue.

Comment: We used a common development environment for all our projects. It was a set of build tools and configuration files. Over time, it became to increase in size and require support. We decided to abandon this common environment and enhance the isolation of projects from each other. So, now we put all required build tools and configuration files in project directory. Previously, we had to keep up all projects up to date with development environment, now we don't need. And now we can just checkout a project and build it virtually on any machine with SDK.

Answer (score 0):

My team uses a separate build project in Eclipse that stores the ivysettings.xml file. The IvyDE plugin provides the Ivy dependency container that the Java projects can use. IvyDE can optionally allow inter-project dependency resolution, but this is off by default.

I'd suggest changing the order of classpath entries in the Ivy Classpath configuration to lexical, otherwise it shows dependencies in the order of the ivy.xml file.

Each project should have their own ivy.xml file - we also follow the same pattern as Alexey uses of using the project's top-level directory.

I've never used an ivyconf.xml file - a quick google suggests this is an alternative (older, deprecated?) name for the ivysettings.xml file.

You will need to write your own ivysettings.xml file to tell IvyDE where your repositories are and which resolvers to use. Leave a comment if you're interested in an example ivysettings.xml file.

Which repositories are you using? Maven Central? Setting up your own repository with Nexus, Artifactory or just using the file system?